# Stuck on single row subquery returning more than one row in SQL update statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, subquery, case

Hoping somebody might be able to shine some light on this predicament.  How can I work around this, and why does SQL think it's returning multiple lines.  It's just a case statement which should return one row, and the PIDMs are unique.

```
UPDATE SCARF.STUDENT
SET IS_PARENT =
(SELECT 
       CASE WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'N'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YS'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YA'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YB'
       END
FROM 
    GENERAL.GORSRVR, GENERAL.GOBSRVR
WHERE 
    GORSRVR_PIDM = GOBSRVR_PIDM
    AND GORSRVR_PIDM = student.MPIDM
    AND GOBSRVR_NAME = 'SB564'
    AND GORSRVR_NAME = GOBSRVR_NAME
    AND GOBSRVR_COMPLETE_IND = 'Y'
    AND GORSRVR_QUESTION_NO = 1);
```

Comment: run the select in its own and you  get at least 2 rows, also JOINs are sql standard for 30 years now, you alsovshould use them

Comment: [**Bad habits** to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Yea I don't care.  It still works, and all the developers on my team still use it because we work with Banner, which is written this way and we're not going to 'fix' a million lines of code.  Thanks for the 100th reminder form snobs on here.

Answer (score 1):

not sure exactly why the exists statement fixed it, but now it updates properly.

```
UPDATE SCARF.STUDENT
SET IS_PARENT =
(SELECT 
       CASE WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'N'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YS'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YA'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YB'
       END
FROM 
    GENERAL.GORSRVR, GENERAL.GOBSRVR
WHERE 
    GORSRVR_PIDM = GOBSRVR_PIDM
    AND GORSRVR_PIDM = MPIDM
    AND GOBSRVR_NAME = 'SB564'
    AND GORSRVR_NAME = GOBSRVR_NAME
    AND GOBSRVR_COMPLETE_IND = 'Y'
    AND GORSRVR_QUESTION_NO = 1)
where exists
    (SELECT 
       CASE WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'N'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YS'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YA'
       WHEN GORSRVR_RESPONSE_4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'YB'
       END
FROM 
    GENERAL.GORSRVR, GENERAL.GOBSRVR
WHERE 
    GORSRVR_PIDM = GOBSRVR_PIDM
    AND GORSRVR_PIDM = MPIDM
    AND GOBSRVR_NAME = 'SB564'
    AND GORSRVR_NAME = GOBSRVR_NAME
    AND GOBSRVR_COMPLETE_IND = 'Y'
    AND GORSRVR_QUESTION_NO = 1)
    ;
```